# vue-element-admin this.$router.push can't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use vue-element-admin to make a button for registering, so I copy the file folder which name is `src/view/login`,and rename it as `register`,then in the file folder which name is `src/router/index` add the code block as follow:

```
 {
    path: '/regist',
    component: () => import('@/views/regist/index'),
    hidden: true
  }
```

then in the file which name is `src/views/login/index.vue`, I add a button as follow:

```js
<el-button :loading="loading" type="primary" style="width:100%;margin:0 0 30px;" @click="handleRegist">New？Register</el-button>
```

the `handleRegist` as follow：

```
handleRegist(){
      this.$router.push({path: "/regist"});
      console.log("can't get the regist page")
}
```

**I expected when I click the registered button, then get a regist page. however, when I click that button and it still show the login page.**

and after clicking the registered button, the router path is

```
http://localhost:9527/#/login?redirect=%2Fregist
```

**which I expect it is `http://localhost:9527/#/regist`**

the description of the problem is end. and I have try to do something to solve this problem:

file path:`src/permission.js`,I add the code block  in `router.beforeEach(async(to, from, next) =>` as follow :

```
if(to.path === '/register'){
    next()
  }
```

but I get the same problem as above.

**what should I do to get the register page**,please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Are you importing a correct component `component: () => import('@/views/regist/index')` ? You have renamed it as `register` but using `regist` while importing.

Comment: I have checked,and import a correct component,thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you use this?

```
this.$router.push('/regist')
```

what happens if you use this method to push to a different view, like '/' ?

Comment: I have try the method as follows:`this.$router.push('/') `,and I get similar problem as above,the only deffirent is the router path I get is `http://localhost:9527/#/login?redirect=%2Fdocumentation`,which I expected it is `http://localhost:9527/#/regist`,**I guess it is because some unknonwn operation to change the router path in the specific file `src/view/login/index.vue`.Because when I try `this.$router.push('/login') ` in the file ``src/view/regist/index.vue` is worked.**  I still don't know how to fix it,anyway,thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: the %2F would be a forward slash (/). I've glanced at the vue-element-admin but that is a lot of code. Try this.$router.push('regist'). The forward slash seems to be an issue.